# KeyError: 'x' keeps stopping my code from working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, statistics

I was working on some statistics homework for my university class and for some reason I keep getting KeyError: 'x'
I'm not sure what this means or how to change it so that the code works. It says that it has something to do with the pandas library (File "pandas_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 109, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type).

This is the code I was using:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

array = np.loadtxt(r'C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\University\Statistics\Body-Data.csv', skiprows = 1, delimiter=',' )
print('questions a), b) and c) \n', array)

sorted_array = array[np.argsort(array[:,1])]
print('question d) \n', sorted_array)

print("median: \n")
median = np.median(sorted_array, axis = 0)
print(median)

print("mean: \n")
mean = np.mean(sorted_array, axis = 0)
print(mean)

print("standard deviation: \n")
standard_deviation = np.std(sorted_array, axis = 0)
print(standard_deviation)

print("variance: \n")
variance = (standard_deviation)**2
print(variance)

print("covariance: \n")
covariance = np.cov(sorted_array)
print(covariance)

print("Correlation matrix: \n")
df = pd.DataFrame(sorted_array)
CorrMatrix = df.corr()
print(CorrMatrix)

print("Absolute relative fequency: \n")
data1 = np.ravel(sorted_array).T
dg = pd.Series(data1).value_counts()
print(dg)

print("Histogram in plot section of Spyder editor: \n")
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=len(df.columns), figsize=(10,5))
for col, ax in zip(df, axes):
    df[col].value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar(ax=ax, title=col)
plt.tight_layout()    
plt.show()
    
df.plot()    
df.plot(kind='scatter',x='x',y='y')
```

Comment: check if `x` is present in the output of `df.columns`

Comment: "It says that it has something to do with the pandas library" First, please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough. Then, try to trace through and diagnose the logic of the error. For example, look at the stack trace for the last thing that happened within your code. Think about what a `KeyError` actually is (hint: an `Error` caused by a missing `Key` in a dictionary) and why that could be happening (`pandas` is trying to look something up in a dictionary; can you think which one?)

Comment: Other useful things you can try are to read the documentation, and to recall what your intent was for the code in question. For example, here you wanted to plot data from the dataframe, using the `x` column for the x-axis (hence `x='x'`), yes? So, does the dataframe actually have that column?

Comment: Even if i run the code right after the creation of the dataframe I still encounter the same problem. I thought because I specified "x" in by scatter plot it would work.

Comment: "I thought because I specified "x" in by scatter plot" What do you mean by "specified 'x'", how exactly is it specified, and what is the logic by which you decided to do so?

Comment: I have the correct pandas libraries and everything, it spits out like 100 different errors relationg to random pandas files for some reason.

Comment: honestly, I'm not really good at this at all and I'm not sure what you meant with KeyErrors. I assumed that KeyError: "x" meant that my x variable is in some way incapacitated. Really don't know.

Comment: The first comment by @AnuragDabas was probably correct. In more detail, your last line is `df.plot(kind='scatter',x='x',y='y')`. The part `x='x'` is trying to select a column in your DataFrame, and you probably don't have a column named `'x'`. (If you posted a [mcve] you would get an answer more quickly, since without data, we don't know the full picture.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make a simple dataframe:

```
In [305]: df2=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3),columns=['a','b','c'])
In [306]: df2
Out[306]: 
   a   b   c
0  0   1   2
1  3   4   5
2  6   7   8
3  9  10  11
In [307]: df2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   a       4 non-null      int64
 1   b       4 non-null      int64
 2   c       4 non-null      int64
dtypes: int64(3)
memory usage: 224.0 bytes
```

If I use `plot` as you do, but with column names, I get a plot:

```
In [308]: df2.plot(kind='scatter', x='a',y='b')
Out[308]: <AxesSubplot:xlabel='a', ylabel='b'>
```

But if I use a generic `x`, `y`, think, as I think you do, that you are specifying axis labels or something like that, I get your error.

```
In [309]: df2.plot(kind='scatter', x='x',y='y')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'x'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-309-89538e1b65fa>", line 1, in <module>
    df2.plot(kind='scatter', x='x',y='y')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 900, in __call__
    return plot_backend.plot(data, x=x, y=y, kind=kind, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/__init__.py", line 61, in plot
    plot_obj.generate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py", line 280, in generate
    self._make_plot()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py", line 1042, in _make_plot
    data[x].values,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'x'
```

I included the full **traceback**, which you should have done as well.

Right before the key error, it uses `self.columns.get_loc(key)`

Look at the `columns` of the dataframe:

```
In [310]: df2.columns
Out[310]: Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

`get_loc` works for a valid name:

```
In [312]: df2.columns.get_loc('b')
Out[312]: 1
```

But fails for an invalid one:

```
In [313]: df2.columns.get_loc('x')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'x'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-313-537e5b0cd441>", line 1, in <module>
    df2.columns.get_loc('x')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'x'
```

I'm showing all this detail because you need to learn to look for clues like this in the error message. With a basic Python `dict`, a KeyError means you tried to fetch an entry that does not exist.  In `pandas`, columns are commonly identified by name, and `KeyError` is similar - you are looking for a column name that does not exist.

I'll admit that the docs for `df.plot` are a bit fuzzy regarding the meaning of the `x` and `y` parameters.

```
x : label or position, default None
    Only used if data is a DataFrame.
y : label, position or list of label, positions, default None
    Allows plotting of one column versus another. Only used if data is a DataFrame.
```

There is a separate `xlabel` parameter.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether x is present in your output of df.columns.

A KeyError will most often mean the key is not present in the df.